# Why is not my react router v6 code work, the navigate is not loading component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner so please bear with me, I have this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apple-basket-with-router-v6-gcjut?file=/src/routes.jsx) where I learn about the latest [React Router v6 Preview](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/) and im stuck configuring the routes.

I have simply just a button when clicking it should open a new page like:

```
navigate("/NotFoundView", { replace: true });
```

and my routs are very simple like:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Header />,
    children: [
      { path: "NotFoundView", element: <NotFoundView /> },
      { path: "404", element: <NotFoundView /> },
      { path: "*", element: <NotFoundView /> }
    ]
  }
];
```

The app starts and show the `<Header />,` ok but not the `NotFoundView` when click button, is not rendered?

Any ide?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Outlet component inside Header:

```
return (
    <div>
    <header>
      <NavBar
        navbarState={navbarOpen}
        handleNavbar={handleNavbar}
        toggle={drawerToggleClickHandler}
        visible={visible}
      />
    </header>
    <Articles/>
    <Outlet/> // your are missing this.
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to render NotFoundView outside of Header component you don't need nested routes. This should work:

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", element: <Header />},
  { path: "NotFoundView", element: <NotFoundView /> },
  { path: "404", element: <NotFoundView /> },
  { path: "*", element: <NotFoundView /> }
];
```

Comment: I add `<Outlet/>` like you suggest but nothing changes how do I access `children` like in my code that I need to learn. When I add  `<Outlet/>` and your `routes` you suggest then my Codesandbox work. What is the purpose of `children`?

Comment: The Outlet element is used as a placeholder for the child route. In this case NotFoundView will be render as Header's child.